# Asp.netMvc join two tables with linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables Employees and Tasks i want to select all tasks that has employee name with linq-query

This is Tasks table:

```
  ID  TaskName  description  employeeIDTo  employeeIDFrom  DateStart
```

This is Employees table:

```
  EmpID  Name  Age
```

`employeeIDTo` and `employeeIDFrom`  foreign-key to `EmpID`

I want to get this result for tasks table:

```
 ID  TaskName  description  EmpID  EmpID  DateStart
```

Comment: do you use linq lambda

Comment: @hasan yes but i don't know how this query will be , i want to select all tasks with employee-name that assigned to this employee

Comment: are you understand what i want ?

Comment: yes i understand, do you use entity? and can you share your controller code where you get Task and Employee data

Answer (score 0):

```
from tsk in Tasks 
join emp in Employees  on tsk.employeeIDTo equals emp.EmpID 
where emp.Name="YOURNAME"
select new { tsk.ID , tsk.TaskName,tsk.Description,emp.EmpID,tsk.DateStart}
```